# Main page wrapper should be centered but appearing left on tablets

Tags: android, html, css

I have a centrally positioned container for my page content called #main. It is positioned absolutely as I wanted some space above the container. The centering therefore works with negative margins and a left:50% instead of using margin:auto.
The problem is that on my Android tablet in both chrome and stock browser, the website renders displaced to the left. This shouldn't be possible as the CSS should put it slap bang in the middle.

```
#main
{
position: absolute;
color: black;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -475px;
margin-top: 40px;
width: 950px;
height: 1600px; 
background: #6B6B6B;
border: solid 1px black;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #444444;
}
```

Interestingly I just removed the negative left margin code from above. On everything but my Android tab, it renders as expected with the container halfway across the browser window. On my Android it is snuggly positioned against the right hand side of the window. I am guessing that if you perform a -475px from THIS position, that results in the left offset. However, why is the main container not just overflowing the right edge before the margin moves it back? Why is 50% left not resulting in 50% left?

As always all discussion and advice gratefully accepted.

EDIT:
Further info, just tried removing absolute position, left 50% and using margin:auto. The main container is STILL on the left.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/EgDRK/1/)

To get something to center you tend not to use `margin:auto;` but `margin:0 auto;`.

Also the main reason you seem to not want to use relative positioning is so that you can have the #main div floating slightly from the top. Relative positioning allows this just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Whislt yep, position relative does let me use margin: 0 auto, the wrapper is still stuck in the left of the window.

Comment: Added info, I've checked all the text scaling and other accessibility features in the Android browsers. These don't seem to be jaffing it up.